# memory management for large phylogenetic distance matrix saved as a pd.desc

Tags: r, matrix, memory, phylogeny

I'm looking to use `iCAMP::bNRI.cm()` which requires a phylogenetic distance matrix as an actual matrix.  However, my matrix is huge and saved as

```
new("big.matrix.descriptor", description = list(sharedType = "FileBacked", 
    filename = "pd.bin", dirname = "/dirpath/", 
    totalRows = 5122L, totalCols = 5122L, rowOffset = c(0, 5122
    ), colOffset = c(0, 5122), nrow = 5122, ncol = 5122, rowNames = NULL, 
    colNames = NULL, type = "double", separated = FALSE))
```

which I can load as a descriptor.  How can I specify to `iCAMP::bNRI.cm()` that my descriptor is the matrix without breaking the memory bank?

```
bnri.whole <- bNRI.cm(comm=otu, dis=descriptor?, nworker = 4, memo.size.GB = 50...)
```

Thanks!